# The statue of a sequence of finite projections

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, baer-rings

Let $A$ be a Baer $*$-ring. Let $\{p_n\}$  be a sequence of **finite projections** in $A$. True or false?

Suppose that there is no  $N$ with $p_n=p_{n+1}$ for $n\geq N$. We have then  $\inf_{1\leq n\leq d} p_n=0$ for some $d\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No. There exist lots of examples (e.g., all finite type II W* factors) with (lots of) descending sequences of nonzero projections $\{p_n \}$ with  $p_k \leq p_{k+1}$ and the traces go to zero (so the infimum is zero. The condition you require is a type of noetherian condition, which in the AW* case, would force it to have all simple quotients by ideals to be finite dimensional, a very strong condition.

Comment: @DavidHandelman, Thanks a lot, very helpful comment.